# Combine multiple regression exposure coeffients in the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

This is a reproduceable example of my data and code

```
    set.seed(42) 
n <- 100
dat = data.frame(ID = 1:n,
                 age=sample(50:80, n, replace=TRUE),
                 Sex = sample(c(1,2), n, replace=TRUE),
                 Years_of_education = sample((0:25), n, replace=TRUE),
                 Exposure_A_Quantile = sample(c(1,2,3,4), n, replace=TRUE),
                 Exposure_B_Quantile = sample(c(1,2,3,4), n, replace=TRUE),
                 outcome = c(rep(0,each=73),rep(1,each=27))
                 )
  
dat$age = as.numeric(dat$age)
dat$Sex = factor (dat$Sex, levels = c(1,2), labels = c("M","F"))
dat$Years_of_education = as.numeric(dat$Years_of_education)
dat$Exposure_A_Quantile = factor(dat$Exposure_A_Quantile, levels = c(1,2,3,4),labels = c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"))
dat$Exposure_B_Quantile = factor(dat$Exposure_B_Quantile, levels = c(1,2,3,4),labels = c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"))

Logistic_regression_A = glm(outcome~Exposure_A_Quantile+age+Sex+Years_of_education,data = dat, family = "binomial")
Logistic_regression_B = glm(outcome~Exposure_B_Quantile+age+Sex+Years_of_education,data = dat, family = "binomial")
summary(Logistic_regression_A)
summary(Logistic_regression_B)
```

I want to make this graph that illustrate the exposure A and exposure B as a forest plots side by side WITHOUT other variables.
[image: Graph I want to make - multiple forest plots side by side presenting only exposure var]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `broom` to get tidy results from your models, bind the output of the two together, filter the results to the coefficients you want, then plot using ggplot:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

bind_rows(tidy(Logistic_regression_A), 
          tidy(Logistic_regression_B), .id = "Exposure") %>%
  mutate(Exposure = c("A", "B")[as.numeric(Exposure)]) %>%
  filter(grepl("Exposure", term)) %>%
  mutate(lower = estimate - 1.96 * std.error,
         upper = estimate + 1.96 * std.error,
         term = gsub("_", " ", term)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(estimate, term)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = lower, xmax = upper), height = 0,
                 color = "red3", alpha = 0.8, size = 2) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4, fill = "white") +
  labs(x = "Log odds [CI]", y = NULL) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ Exposure, drop = TRUE, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9),
        strip.text = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]